# How to write an ArrayList<String[]> to a .csv file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist, data-structures

Say I have an ArrayList of String arrays like so:

```
    ArrayList<String[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    arrayList.add(new String[]{"hello", "goodbye"});
    arrayList.add(new String[]{"yoyo", "fofo"});
    arrayList.add(new String[]{"foo", "bar"});
```

What would be the simplest way to conver this to a .csv file in Java? I had some data that I manipulated to this particular data structure since ArrayLists are dynamic and I used String arrays inside since the number of columns in the data won't change, and we can just keep adding more arrays to the ArrayList for every new 'row' in the .csv output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to do is as follows:
You might have to add some checking and stuff like that

// code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class a{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add(new String("hello"));
        arrayList.add(new String("yoyo"));
        arrayList.add(new String("foo"));
        try{
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter("sample.csv");
            PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(file);
            for (String name: arrayList){
            write.println(name);
        }
        write.close();
    }
    catch(IOException exe){
        System.out.println("Cannot create file");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i added a nested for loop to that solution to handle the original data structure in question: ArrayList<String[]>. thanks anyways!

Comment: Yes, no problem! Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to write String array to a file, you can iterate through the array and write into the file

Example

```
List<String[]>arrayList= new ArrayList<String[]>();
arrayList.add(new String[]{"hello", "goodbye"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"yoyo", "fofo"});
arrayList.add(new String[]{"foo", "bar"});

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
for(String[] data : arrayList) {
  writer.write(String.join(",", data );
}
```

If you are looking for advanced usage, here is one possibility by using [CSV Java Utility](https://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html). Using this you can read & write CSV data easily.

Here is the example

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import com.Ostermiller.util.CSVPrinter;

public class CSVUtil{

        
    public static CSVPrinter getCSVPrinter(File outputDir, String tabname,
            boolean append) throws FileNotFoundException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {

        // Output filename
        File f = new File(outputDir, tabname + ".csv");

        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f, append);
        BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fo, 500000);
        OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(streamWriter);

        // Intialize the CSV Printer
        CSVPrinter csvout = new CSVPrinter(bw);
        csvout.changeDelimiter('\t');
        // csvout.setAutoFlush(true);
        csvout.setAlwaysQuote(true);
        csvout.setLineEnding("\r\n");

        return csvout;
    }

}
```

Usage :

```
CSVPrinter  csvPrinter= CSVUtil.getCSVPrinter(outDir, "fileName", 
                                                        true);
csvPrinter.writeln(new String[] {"Data1","Data2","Data3"});
```

Comment: I don't think the factory pattern has any business answering the question "what's the simplest way to.." anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Open/create a file
2. Iterate through the ArrayList and print each pair on a line, or however you want it
3. Close the file

Best would be, in my opinion, to not use any libraries, because you don't really need to.

Here's a basic tutorial on how to write to a file: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_create.asp

Example:

```
try {
  FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("filename.txt");
  myWriter.write("Files in Java might be tricky, but it is fun enough!");
  myWriter.close();
  System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occurred.");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's a basic tutorial on how to iterate through an ArrayList: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-loop-arraylist-in-java/

Example:

```
for (String[] entry : arrayList) {            
       System.out.println(entry);       
  }
```

Good luck!

PS: I'm intentionally not giving you the complete code to copy/paste, so you actually learn something

Comment: PPS: If you want one pair per line, you might want to write a line break (\n in Linux, \r\n in Windows) after each pair.